# I want to zero to come to most bottom so don't have any gap

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I want the zero to come to bottom so I don't have a gap here how can I do it

[image]

shouldn't have any gap

I can't find any api to make it work.
tried putting -10 as a point but it just putting that -10 into zero place not working.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`scaleMargins`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/PriceScaleOptions#scalemargins) option within the [PriceScaleOptions](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/PriceScaleOptions) to adjust the margin placed above and below the highest and lowest points on the chart.